# How to add a product box to a Rack and specify what type of product that Rack is. Starting the Run model, the product box will be on the Rack

Tags: data-warehouse, warehouse

How can we add product boxes to the Rack and identify that Rack as a best-selling product? By starting the Run model, the product boxes will be on the Rack. Improving the efficiency of picking products within the warehouse. I'm trying to add boxes to a rack and identify what type of products the rack holds using ABC analysis.

I'm trying to add boxes to a rack and identify what type of products the rack holds using ABC analysis.

Comment: You probably need to provide better tags and/or a better explanation of what you are talking about - otherwise no-one who might be able to help you is going to see your question. This came up in my feed because I monitor questions about data warehouses (i.e. database IT systems) but your question doesn’t seem to be about that. What’s a RUN model? What’s ABC analysis? Are you talking about a physical warehouse?